# how to pause and stop media player in another activity in android

Tags: java, android

I am using a list view and a custom adapter list view contain songs and it shown in activity (fayrouz) and I want to make a button in this activity to stop the mediaplayer.
I have already created the mediaplayer in the musicadapter.

Here is my code:

```
public class activity_fayrouz extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    private AudioManager mAudioManager;

    private Button  stopper;

    MediaPlayer mp ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fayrouz);

        stopper = (Button) findViewById(R.id.st) ;

        stopper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });

    //        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) 
    getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        final ArrayList<music> musics = new ArrayList<>();
        musics.add(new music("shady", "fayrouz", R.raw.shady));
        musics.add(new music("ana L habiby", "fayrouz", R.raw.ana_l_habiby));
        musics.add(new music("alamony", "fayrouz", R.raw.alamony));
        musics.add(new music("habitaak bl saief", "fayrouz", R.raw.habitak_bl_saif));
        musics.add(new music("nsam 3alina el hawa", "fayrouz", R.raw.nsam_aalina_el_hawa));
        musics.add(new music("e7na w el qamar jeraan", "fayrouz", R.raw.e7na_w_el_qamar_jeran));
        musics.add(new music("shady", "fayrouz", R.raw.shady));

        musics.add(new music("shady", "fayrouz", R.raw.shady));
        musics.add(new music("ana L habiby", "fayrouz", R.raw.ana_l_habiby));
        musics.add(new music("alamony", "fayrouz", R.raw.alamony));
        musics.add(new music("habitaak bl saief", "fayrouz", R.raw.habitak_bl_saif));
        musics.add(new music("nsam 3alina el hawa", "fayrouz", R.raw.nsam_aalina_el_hawa));
        musics.add(new music("e7na w el qamar jeraan", "fayrouz", R.raw.e7na_w_el_qamar_jeran));

        musicAdapter adapter = new musicAdapter(this, musics);
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I want this stop button to stop the mediaplayer which was created in the music adapter

music adapter :

```
  if(listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }


    final music my_music = (music) getItem(position);
    TextView songTitle = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.song);
    songTitle.setText(my_music.getSong());
    TextView artistTitle = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.artist);
    artistTitle.setText(my_music.getArtist());



   mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    Button play = (Button) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.play);
    Button    pause = (Button) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.pause) ;
    Button   stop = (Button) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.stop) ;

play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


  mp.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a public method in your music adapter class that stops the media player and call that method in your stopper button onClick;

```
public void stopMediaPlayer() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
}

    stopper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            adapter.stopMediaPlayer();
        }
    });
```